# Websphere - application error during start

Tags: java, websphere, war

I have an issue during start of application. I made a WAR file which runs in tomcat well. But i need to deploy it into websphere application server (8.5.5.4). JVM edited - installed IBM java 1.7 and xmx to 1,8GB.
After deploy of application code below can be found in logs

```
2015-01-28 12:13:48,733 INFO [WebContainer : 3] [com.atlassian.confluence.lifecycle] contextInitialized Starting Confluence 5.5.3 [build 5515 based on commit hash dc14a8a1bb8ff5f410b8fec10fffebe66c51617e]
2015-01-28 12:13:50,672 WARN [WebContainer : 3] [atlassian.config.xml.AbstractDom4jXmlConfigurationPersister] saveDocumentAtomically Unable to move D:\test\cfwshome\confluence.cfg.xml5794152920166961085tmp to D:\test\cfwshome\confluence.cfg.xml. Falling back to non-atomic overwrite.
2015-01-28 12:13:51,020 INFO [WebContainer : 3] [atlassian.plugin.manager.DefaultPluginManager] init Initialising the plugin system
2015-01-28 12:13:51,169 WARN [WebContainer : 3] [osgi.container.felix.ExportsBuilder] getUrlClassLoaders ignoring non-URLClassLoader class com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader
2015-01-28 12:13:51,170 WARN [WebContainer : 3] [osgi.container.felix.ExportsBuilder] getUrlClassLoaders ignoring non-URLClassLoader class com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader
2015-01-28 12:13:51,171 WARN [WebContainer : 3] [osgi.container.felix.ExportsBuilder] getUrlClassLoaders ignoring non-URLClassLoader class com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader
2015-01-28 12:13:51,171 WARN [WebContainer : 3] [osgi.container.felix.ExportsBuilder] getUrlClassLoaders ignoring non-URLClassLoader class org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader
2015-01-28 12:13:51,184 WARN [WebContainer : 3] [osgi.container.felix.ExportsBuilder] collectClassPath Missing manifest prevents deep scan of 'file:/D:/SOFT/IBM/WS/APP/deploytool/itp/batch2.jar'
2015-01-28 12:26:05,878 WARN [Deferrable Alarm : 3] [ws.runtime.component.ThreadMonitorImpl] logToJSR47Logger WSVR0605W: Podproces "WebContainer : 3" (00000065) je aktivní po dobu 743 919 a může být zablokovaný. Na serveru je celkem 1 podprocesů, které mohou být zablokované.
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.getLastModifiedTime(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.lastModified(File.java:950)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:231)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:161)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:169)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:133)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.container.felix.ExportsBuilder.getUrlClassPath(ExportsBuilder.java:356)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.container.felix.ExportsBuilder.generateExports(ExportsBuilder.java:257)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.container.felix.ExportsBuilder.determineExports(ExportsBuilder.java:175)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.container.felix.ExportsBuilder.getExports(ExportsBuilder.java:127)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.container.felix.FelixOsgiContainerManager.start(FelixOsgiContainerManager.java:249)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.container.felix.FelixOsgiContainerManager.onStart(FelixOsgiContainerManager.java:205)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at 
..
..
..
```

another part of stack trace (as i mentioned in last comment bellow)

```
[30 January 15 14: 48: 28: 836 GMT] 0000007c ContextLoader E org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
                                  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'macroIconManager' Defined in class path resource [services / pluginServiceContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'httpRetrievalService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'httpRetrievalService' Defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SettingsManager' Defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'upgradeManager' while setting bean property 'upgradeManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'upgradeManager' Defined in class path resource [upgradeSubsystemContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'contentPermissionConstraintsUpgradeTask' while setting bean property 'schemaUpgradeTasks' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contentPermissionConstraintsUpgradeTask' Defined in class path resource [upgradeSubsystemContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'contentPermissionConstraintsCleaner' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contentPermissionConstraintsCleaner' Defined in class path resource [upgradeSubsystemContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'contentEntityManager' while setting bean property 'contentEntityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contentEntityManager' Defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'linkManager' while setting bean property 'linkManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'linkManager' Defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'outgoingLinksExtractor' while setting bean property 'outgoingLinksExtractor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'outgoingLinksExtractor' Defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'xmlEventReaderFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xmlEventReaderFactory' Defined in class path resource [renderingContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.atlassian.confluence.content.render.xhtml.DefaultXmlEventReaderFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class XMLInputFactory does not recognize the property "com.ctc.wstx.normalizeAttrValues".
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:495)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:162)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:925)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.creat eBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:835)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (AccessController.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
..
..


 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'httpRetrievalService' Defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SettingsManager' Defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'upgradeManager' while setting bean property 'upgradeManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'upgradeManager' Defined in class path resource [upgradeSubsystemContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'contentPermissionConstraintsUpgradeTask' while setting bean property 'schemaUpgradeTasks' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contentPermissionConstraintsUpgradeTask' Defined in class path resource [upgradeSubsystemContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'contentPermissionConstraintsCleaner' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contentPermissionConstraintsCleaner' Defined in class path resource [upgradeSubsystemContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'contentEntityManager' while setting bean property 'contentEntityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contentEntityManager' Defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'linkManager' while setting bean property 'linkManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'linkManager' Defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'outgoingLinksExtractor' while setting bean property 'outgoingLinksExtractor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'outgoingLinksExtractor' Defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'xmlEventReaderFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xmlEventReaderFactory' Defined in class path resource [renderingContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.atlassian.confluence.content.render.xhtml.DefaultXmlEventReaderFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class XMLInputFactory does not recognize the property "com.ctc.wstx.normalizeAttrValues".
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (AccessController.java:303)
..
..
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SettingsManager' Defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'upgradeManager' while setting bean property 'upgradeManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'upgradeManager' Defined in class path resource [upgradeSubsystemContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'contentPermissionConstraintsUpgradeTask' while setting bean property 'schemaUpgradeTasks' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contentPermissionConstraintsUpgradeTask' Defined in class path resource [upgradeSubsystemContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'contentPermissionConstraintsCleaner' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contentPermissionConstraintsCleaner' Defined in class path resource [upgradeSubsystemContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'contentEntityManager' while setting bean property 'contentEntityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contentEntityManager' Defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'linkManager' while setting bean property 'linkManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'linkManager' Defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'outgoingLinksExtractor' while setting bean property 'outgoingLinksExtractor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'outgoingLinksExtractor' Defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Can not resolve reference to bean 'xmlEventReaderFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xmlEventReaderFactory' Defined in class path resource [renderingContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.atlassian.confluence.content.render.xhtml.DefaultXmlEventReaderFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class XMLInputFactory does not recognize the property "com.ctc.wstx.normalizeAttrValues".
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
```

Comment: Could you translate the error message from your stacktrace to english?

Comment: @AndréStannek "WSVR0605W: Thread "WebContainer : 3" (00000065) has been active for 743,919 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 1 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung." As far as I can tell, either the application is simply doing a large amount of work, or the filesystem is slow/hung (network file system?), or there's a JVM defect of some kind.

Comment: I've seen that message when connecting to a remote resource that held its connection open when an error occurred, and never sent a completion message to the Java program consuming it.  It's not *technically* a fatal error by itself, but over time they can build up and cause real problems.

Comment: Sorry for bad lang in stack trace. the english stack trace is :
`[ws.runtime.component.ThreadMonitorImpl] logToJSR47Logger WSVR0605W: Thread "WebContainer: 3" (00000065) is active for 743 919 and can be blocked. The server has 1 threads, which can be blocked.`